# SML: pattern with constants?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to write a pattern matching function in SML but I get this error

`Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: -`

I am trying to do something as such:

```
fun illegal (c:char) i j n m =
    let
        fun legal (#"A") 0 j = true
           |legal (#"B") i 0 = true
           |legal (#"C") i n = true
           |legal (#"D") m j = true
           | legal c  i j     = false
     in
        if (legal c i j = false) then 0
        else i
     end

**I suspect that the problem is that my n,m are two constants that have been valued right before. Any help appreciated
(I searched online and here I added parentheses in my chars, and tried some other stuff but my error persisted)**
```

Comment: I see two possibilities: either the error is referring to something else, or your original code has a typo that got fixed when you posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you pattern match, something like `i` is not checking to see if it has the same value as the existing `i` binding, but it's introducing a new `i` binding.

When you have:

```
legal (#"A") 0 j = true
```

You're really looking for is something like:

```
legal (#"A") 0 j2 = j = j2
```

Comment: what I think i say with my code is "if you get char "A" and then 0 and then any number" then return true .." , you are saying that ML tries to solve it like an equation for j ? I 've got a little bit confused

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression you were looking for `#"A"`, `0`, and then the same value as the `i` provided to `illegal`. When pattern matching a value you won't be using, you may find it helpful to use `_`. So `fun legal (#"A") 0 j = true` becomes `fun legal #"A" 0 _ = true`. _The extra parens are unnecessary._